# How to only show related objects in Django Admin screens

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have an app where I want administrators to be able to create events via the admin view. I have members, who will have multiple cars and attend multiple meets. I want to record which vehicle they used at a meet.

In the django admin view for a member, I can manage their cars successfully and only cars belonging to that member show up in the `inline` on the Member Admin page, but when attempting to manage meets, all cars are listed, not only cars belonging to that member.

I want the same list of cars from the CarInline to appear in the MeetInline - i.e. cars registered to the member. Any ideas how to achieve this?

I *think* that the issue is  that the `Meet` model has a ManyToMany relationship with the `Car` model but wasn't sure how else to model this.

*models.py*

```
class Member(models.model):
    member_number = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=30)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Car(models.model) 
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    registration = models.CharField(max_length=80)


class Meet(models.model)
    meet_date = models.DateTimeField()
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    car = models.ManyToManyField(Car)
```

*admin.py*

```
class CarInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Car
    extra = 0
    fields = ["registration"]

class MeetInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Meet
    extra = 0
    fields =["meet_date", "car"]

class MemberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = [
        "is_active"
    ]
    search_fields = ["member_number"]
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {"fields": ["member_number", "is_active"]}),
    ]
    inlines = [CarInline, MeetInline]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Member, Car, Meet


class CarInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Car
    extra = 0
    fields = ["registration"]


class MeetInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Meet
    extra = 0
    fields = ["meet_date", "car"]

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        """
        Override the default formfield for the 'car' field to only show cars
        belonging to the current member.
        """
        formfield = super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)

        if db_field.name == "car":
            member_pk = request.resolver_match.kwargs.get("object_id") // here i have used object_id as pk please change it according to what your pk name is
            if member_pk:
                member = Member.objects.get(pk=member_pk)
                formfield.queryset = member.car_set.all()

        return formfield


class MemberAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ["is_active"]
    search_fields = ["member_number"]
    fieldsets = [(None, {"fields": ["member_number", "is_active"]}),]
    inlines = [CarInline, MeetInline]


admin.site.register(Member, MemberAdmin)
```